# Changing the legend in chartSeries to display values - Quantmod addTA

Tags: r, quantmod

Is it possible to change the legend on the plot displayed in Quantmod so that values are displayed rather than the variable name? For example:

```
library("quantmod")
getSymbols("YHOO")
temp1 <- 6
temp2 <- "SMA"
barChart(YHOO)
addTA(ADX(YHOO, n=temp1, maType=temp2))
```

The legend that is displayed in the plot is `ADX(YHOO, n=temp1, maType=temp2)`. I would like it to display the specific values instead i.e. `ADX(YHOO, n=6, maType='SMA')`.

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). This makes it much easier to understand your problem and to propose a solution.

Comment: Thanks Joshua Ulrich and Paolo Casciello for the improved formatting and corrections.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to do this automatically with `addTA`, because it would need to know which of the the parameters of the `TA` call it needs to evaluate.  But you can do it manually by setting the `legend=` argument yourself.

One way to do it is to use `paste` (or `paste0`).

```
barChart(YHOO)
Legend <- paste0('ADX(YHOO, n=',temp1,', maType=',temp2,')')
addTA(ADX(YHOO, n=temp1, maType=temp2), legend=Legend)
```

Or you could create and manipulate the call to get what you want.

```
barChart(YHOO)
callTA <- call("ADX",quote(YHOO),n=temp1,maType=temp2)
eval(call("addTA", callTA, legend=deparse(callTA)))
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I'd worked out a similar solution to your first suggestion which will also display the output values for the TA in the legend. Unfortunately I haven't worked out how to get the color of the output text to match the relevant color of line on the plot.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a partial solution which displays the values rather than variable names in the legend as well as the relevant output values for the TA. However, unlike the default settings of addTA, the text for each output value doesn't match the colour of the line on the addTA plot. Unfortunately I haven't worked out how to get the text of the output values to match the colour of its relevant line on the addTA plot. Any suggestions?

```
  library("quantmod")
  getSymbols("YHOO")
  barChart(YHOO, subset="last 4 months")
  col <- c("red", "blue", "green", "orange")
  temp1 <- 8
  temp2 <- "SMA"
  temp <- ADX(HLC(YHOO), n=temp1, maType=temp2)
  legend <- rep(NA, NCOL(temp)+1)
  legend[1] <- paste("ADX(HLC(YHOO)", "n=", temp1, "maType=", temp2)
  for(x in 2:(NCOL(temp)+1)){
      legend[x] <- (paste(colnames(temp[,(x-1)]),": ", round(last(temp[,(x-1)]),3), sep=""))
  }
  addTA(temp, legend = legend, col=col)
```